# Need help creating a TFS 2010 build definition

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm in the process of setting up TFS and have created a project with \Main and \Release folders. If I create a build definition (with a CI trigger) I'm assuming that by default the build will trigger whenever a file is checked-in *anywhere* in the project?

How do I configure it to only build solutions under \Main *AND* only when something has been checked-in under \Main? i.e. I don't want it to build if I check-in a file under \Release, for example.

Also, I could do with some pointers on how I go about configuring the build to automatically set the version number (and perhaps other properties like company name, etc.) in a solution's assemblyinfo file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You limit the scope of what is checked by changing the workspace mapping.

To find information on increasing the version number customizing the build, see http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Under the `Workspace` tab, set the `Source Control Folder` depth you want to trigger CI build.
E.g.: `$/Demo/Dev/v2.0`

For versioned build, consider [Versioned TFS 2010 Build](http://versionedtfsbuild.codeplex.com/) and [TfsVersioning](http://tfsversioning.codeplex.com/).

Comment: That's what I suspected. Do I leave 'Build Agent Folder' as '$(SourceDir)' or modify it based on the depth I specify in the 'Source Control Folder'? (This bit confused me as I'm creating the build def on my PC, so it's feasible that the folder I select may not exist on the build machine due to the machines having different disk/folder structures).

Comment: The Build Agent Folder is where the agent pulls the sources to. In case you are building many branches you may want to assign a friendly folder name to represent each branch.